# password expired- windows 7

Tags: windows, passwords

I have an issue with password on some accounts on windows 7.
They all are local accounts and I have tried to set
 net accounts /maxpwage:unlimited
also make password never expired from user management but I still got password has expired 
I cleared all polices on the machine with no luck to unlock accounts
one of the accounts as below:

[image]

---

These accounts were created remotely via batches by another computer but I access them on the actual machine and they are local accounts.

any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the screenshot I can see that the account has expired date not the password. 
Account and password have different expire settings and meanings.

```
net user USERNAME /expires:never
```

If this does not help: Please specify the scenario with more detail (How created and what should not expire, after doing what)?

Further readings:
https://www.top-password.com/blog/differences-between-user-account-expiration-and-password-expiration/